# Dynamically adding HTML inputs in Dash framework

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, dynamic, plotly-dash

I am new to Dash and I am in need of some assistance. I need to create a dynamic number of inputs, but I have no idea how to bind a dynamic number of callback for each slider component. I am only able to create a dynamic number of sliders, but as you can see in the code, I need to hard code the number of callbacks. Is there a better way to to this so that it is more dynamic?

```
@app.callback(
    Output('slider-container', 'children'),
    [Input('button', 'n_clicks')])
def add_sliders(n_clicks):
    return \
        html.Div([
            html.Div([
                html.Div(dcc.Slider(id='slider-{}'.format(i))),
                dcc.Input(
                    id='input-{}'.format(i),
                    placeholder='Graph Name',
                    type='text',
                    value=''
                ),
                html.Div(id='output-{}'.format(i), style={'marginTop': 30})
            ]) for i in range(n_clicks)]
        )


# up to 10 sliders
for i in range(10):
    @app.callback(
        Output('slider-{}'.format(i), 'children'),
        [Input('slider-{}'.format(i), 'value'),
        Input('input-{}'.format(i), 'value')])
    def update_output(slider_i_value, input_i_value):
        return str(slider_i_value) + str(input_i_value)
```

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am trying to add html elements dynamically based on selected drop down option. Can you tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

As of Dash 1.11.0 you have [Pattern Matching Callbacks](https://dash.plotly.com/pattern-matching-callbacks) that do just this. In your case you'd use the one with the `MATCH`.